# Rotate a TransformView around the x-axis when tilting the Phone

Tags: iphone

I have a TransformView with an image (an arrow) inside it, which I have rotated, so that the view lays on the z-axis. Now I want that the image rotates around the x-axis when i tilt the iPhone. Like when I hold my iPhone in the vertical upright position and I tilt it in the flat up Postion I want that the arrow moves smoothly from the z to the y axis and return to the z axis when I tilt it back to the vertical upright position.
Is this possible and how could I implement this?
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: http://www.bdunagan.com/2010/02/16/iphone-tip-rotating-uiview/

Comment: feel free to upvote the comment and close the question.